# How to pass python variable to shell command

Tags: python, bash, unix

Is their any way that i can pass variable value of python to my unix command

Note : var is a python  variable which stores filename with path

```
var='/d/demo/f/f.txt'
```

Want to call `var` to my sed command

```
os.system(bash -c 'sed -i "1i\NAME" var ')
```

This throws me error at `"1i\"` syntax invalid

Comment: BTW, `os.system("something")` runs `sh -c "something"`, so `os.system("bash -c something")` is running `sh -c "bash -c something"` -- two shells when you might not even need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `subprocess.run`, not `os.system()`, and pass an array of individual argument-vector entries.

```
var = '/d/demo/f/f.txt'
subprocess.run(['sed', '-i', r'1i\NAME', var])
```

Each argument needs to be escaped according to *Python* rules, not shell rules; hence using `r'1i\NAME'` for a string with a literal backslash in it. You could also achieve the same effect with `'1i\\NAME'`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response , it work like charm