# Execute a python script with parameters within a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

For my unittests I use a setup which is executed in a `main.py` in the top directory which is executed with several parameters:

```
python3.9 main.py -i f -f Schematic.xml -d Inno -p Testrun -x
```

How do I execute that correctly in the setUp of my unittests?

I am aware this question has been asked often already but I can't get this to work. Most of the solutions suggested on SO just make my unittests get stuck or result in an error.

This one is the closest I could bring it to work but the tests just get stuck and I manually need to continue them:

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python main.py -i f -f Schematic.xml -d Inno -p Testrun -x"), stdout=open("cmd.log", 'ab'))
```

What I don't understand is if there is an input to be or what is expected.
I took the solution from [subprocess.Popen shell=True to shell=False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470965/subprocess-popen-shell-true-to-shell-false) as the previous variant would only get stuck:

```
subprocess.Popen("python main.py -i f -f Schematic.xml -d Inno -p Testrun -x", shell=True)
```

Apparently setting `shell=False` alone is not possible, so I followed the instructions and modified my code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25465793/2516892). If I just set it to false, I only get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python main.py -i f -f Schematic.xml -d Inno -p Testrun -x'
```

So the correct way is supposed to be:

```
subprocess.check_call(['main.py', '-i f -f Schematic.xml -d Inno -p Testrun -x'], shell=False)
```

But again all I get is an error:

```
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main.py
```

Apparently `os` shouldn't be used any more. Also it doesn't work:

```
    os.system('python main.py -i f -f Schematic.xml -d Inno -p Testrun -x')
```

Here I'm getting:

```
sh: main.py: command not found
```

Edit:
It is now "solved", but the solution is not really what I like as I consider it as cheap and doesn't answer the question - why the previous trials didn't work. Despite me being in the home directory just calling main.py that didn't work. I used the absolute path:

```
os.system('python /home/docker/main.py -i f -f Schematic.xml -d Inno -p Testrun -x')
```

I will keep it like this for now, but again. This is not really what I had in mind

Comment: : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536168/need-to-pass-parameter-to-unix-script-at-run-time  this could help you just check

Comment: : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528903/how-to-pass-python-variable-to-shell-command this one as well

Comment: @wovef57249 - the first one is not what I'm looking for and doesn't relate to calling a script. Also using `os.system` is not recommended to be used for Python Scripts

Comment: If `os.system('python main.py')` doesn't find the file (i.e. the script file is not in the current directory), you need to specify the full path to the file. Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: Not running Python as a subprocess of itself is often a superior solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script